# Groovy Modifying Json

Tags: json, groovy

I'm trying to modify a json which I'm reading from a file:

```
String response = new File("response.json").text
```

here is what response looks like:

```
{
  "TerminatingInstances": [
    {
      "InstanceId": "id",
      "CurrentState": {
        "Code": 32,
        "Name": "shutting-down"
      },
      "PreviousState": {
        "Code": 16,
        "Name": "running"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To modify it I did as follows:

```
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
builder.content.TerminatingInstances.InstanceId = "id-updated"
```

but I get `argument type mismatch` error, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's an array of instances inside `TerminatingInstances`

You can either set all of them to the new id with `*.`:

```
builder.content.TerminatingInstances*.InstanceId = "id-updated"
```

Or set just the first one with

```
builder.content.TerminatingInstances[0].InstanceId = "id-updated"
```